# using JavaScript how to disable the location bar in the new window web page, "location=no" is not working

Tags: javascript, html, hide, new-window

I am trying to disable the address bar. I used the "location=no" parameter in the window. open method, but it is not working. could you please help on this issue?

Below is my source code. Please check and help me on this.

First HTML ( From this page I am opening second page in new window)

```html
<html>
    <script>
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>The a element</h1>
        <a href="target.htm" onclick="window.open('https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close', '', 'toolbar=no, directories=no,location=no, status=yes, menubar=no,resize=no, scrollbars=yes');">Open New Window</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second Html : (In new window this HTML page will open)

```html
<html oncontextmenu="return false;">
   <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
      <style>
      </style>
      <script >
        // window.open('file:///C:/Users/Karthik.Ch/Documents/docView.html','winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');
         
         function myFunction() {
                 // window.resizeTo(1024,750);
         }
         
         document.onkeypress = function (event) {
                  event = (event || window.event);
                  return keyFunction(event);
         }
         document.onmousedown = function (event) {
                  event = (event || window.event);
                  return keyFunction(event);
         }
         document.onkeydown = function (event) {
                  event = (event || window.event);
                  return keyFunction(event);
         }
         
         //Disable right click script 
         function clickIE() {
             if (document.all) {
                 alert("Sorry, right-click has been disabled");
                 return false;
              }
         } 
         function clickNS(e) {
                  if (document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
                           if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {
                                    alert("Sorry, right-click has been disabled");
                                    return false;
                           }
                  }
         } 
         if (document.layers){
             document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;
         }else{
                  document.onmouseup=clickNS;
                  document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;
         } 
         
         document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
         
         function keyFunction(event){
                  //Ctrl+Shift+I
                  if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) {
                           alert('The action you performed is unauthorized. Copying any content from this website is restricted');
                  return false;
                  }
                  //Ctrl+Shift+J
                  if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 74) {
                           alert('The action you performed is unauthorized. Copying any content from this website is restricted');
                  return false;
                  }
                  //Ctrl+Shift+U
                  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 85) {
                           alert('The action you performed is unauthorized. Copying any content from this website is restricted');
                  return false;
                  }
                  
                  //Ctrl+V
                  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 86) {
                           alert('The action you performed is unauthorized. Copying any content from this website is restricted');
                  return false;
                  }
                  //F12 || S || F5 || Insert || P || Z || right window key || Windows Menu / Right || Delete || Print Screen || Shift  || Alt ||  Print || Refresh || C || Ctrl || event.keyCode == 67 || event.keyCode == 17
                  if (event.keyCode == 123 || event.keyCode == 83 || event.keyCode == 116 || event.keyCode == 45 || event.keyCode == 80 || event.keyCode == 91 || event.keyCode == 92 || event.keyCode == 93 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 44 || event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 18 || event.keyCode == 42 || event.keyCode == 168 ) {
                      alert('The action you performed is unauthorized. Copying any content from this website is restricted');
                  return false;
                  }
         }
         
         function closeWindow(){
                 //setTimeout('window.close()', 300000)
                 
                 
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="closeWindow()" onresize="myFunction()" oncopy="return false;" onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false;">
      <iframe style="width:1024px" height="750" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp"></iframe>
      <div style="width:1020px;height:750px;background-color:transparent;position:absolute;top:0px;max-width: 100%;">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you see the error in your browser when you click?

Comment: @JaromandaX in-browser console there is no error.

Comment: perhaps it's because you're passing 4 parameters to window.open, that only takes 3 ... url, name and optional options ... so your optional options aren't in the right parameter  -remove the `, ''` that's before `,'postwindow'`

Comment: Yes, I updated the code. and kept three parameters. but still the same issue.
<a href="target.htm" onclick="window.open('https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close', '', 'toolbar=no, directories=no,location=no, status=yes, menubar=no,resize=no, scrollbars=yes');">Open New Window</a>

Comment: why are you using `=0` sometimes and `=no` at others - that's not the problem though - and what is `directories` , that's not documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#toolbar_and_ui_parts_features)

Comment: I removed 0, instead of 0 I used now as no. I update in my code and tested the same issue @JaromandaX

Comment: but I said that wasn't the problem ... read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#popup_condition) and you'll see that as of quite some time ago, you do not have the level of control you used to get when you popup a window - i.e. most of those features are not controllable

Comment: So there is no chance to disable to address bar/location. The requirement is we don't want to show the URL to the end user. if the URL user has seen then he can copy and open in any new tab and see the code and documents links also see and using that links he downloads those documents. this access/visibility we need to restrict to the user. so that is the reason I am planning to hide the address bar/location or after opening the page in a new window I am trying to change the address.

Comment: even without the address being shown the URL is accessible to any user smarter than a 5th grader :p